# xslt select value of c where d equals BBB with local-name

Tags: xslt

```
<abc>
    <loop>
        <a>
            <b>
                <c>hugo</c>
                <d>AAA</d> 
            </b>
        </a>
    </loop>
    <loop>
        <a>
            <b>
                <c>Boss</c>
                <d>BBB</d>
            </b> 
        </a>
    </loop> 
</abc>
```

I am trying to get the value of `c` where `d` equals `BBB`. I am forced to use the local-name and not like `/loop/a/b[d='BBB']/c`

Comment: "*I am forced to use local-name*"  Why is that?

Comment: I dont know the namespace and also because I want to learn using local-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont know the namespace

Perhaps you'd be better off working to fix that, because the alternative is not pretty.

Anyway,  you could use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='abc']/*[local-name()='loop']/*[local-name()='a']/*[local-name()='b'][*[local-name()='d']='BBB']/*[local-name()='c']"/>
```

or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/*/*/*/*[*='BBB']/*[local-name()='c']"/>
```

or anything in-between the two.